# Accordion jQuery, when in line it pushes the 2nd item down with it

Tags: jquery

I have added a jquery for my accordion, the issue is that it when the you click on the picture to drop down to see the list, it pulls the picture down next to it. I would like the pictures to stay inline, I'm not sure how to do this?

http://www.vestedutility.com.au/test2.php#accordion-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your `.location` class which has been assigned to `li`

```
li.location{
    float:left
}
```

The above will definitely disturb your structure and thus change the `padding` as below to be in usual `position` when it was without `float:left`

```
li.location {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px 100px; //Change padding
    float: left; //Keep float left
}
```

> **PS - Its always a good habit to add code to your question instead of link to some site as the link might get broken someday. So always
>   assist your question with some piece of code**

Comment: cheers that works however it doesn't stay in the centre with the different screen?

Comment: @JamesRW That you need to write necessary styles using media queries.. :)